# Interface extends Inteface on LinkedList Generics

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am a little confused about `Interface extends Interface` in a Linked List.
Probably a little code explains it best

**Interface A**

```
public interface Fruit {
    public String getColor();
}
```

**Interface B**

```
 public interface Fruit_alias extends Fruit {
 }
```

**Class Orange**

```
public class Orange implements Fruit {

    @Override
    public String getColor() {
        return "Orange";
    }
    public void pellOrange(){
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkedList<Fruit_alias> f1=new LinkedList<Frucht_alias>();
    f1.push(new Orange()); //gives me an Error

    LinkedList<Fruit> f2=new LinkedList<Frucht>();
    f2.push(new Orange()); // works fine
}
```

Why can I not use `Orange` here? This feels weird to me because I would expect that the interface behave like an object which inherits from a more general object.

Comment: `Orange` implements `Fruit`, not `Fruit_alias`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Fruit_alias` is not super class of Orange but `Fruit` is. A super type can reference sub type in inheritance relation. Change the declaration to:

```
public class Orange implements Fruit_alias {

    @Override
    public String getColor() {
        return "Orange";
    }
    public void pellOrange(){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fruit_alias is not super class of Orange so you can't do it like this.